# use start and stop button in main thread and background thread should be notified according to button

Tags: java, android, multithreading

When i press a start button in main thread, the background thread should be notified and start printing and again when I press the stop button in the main thread, the background thread should stop printing and go back to monitor wait in the background.

The code should be in Java and implemented in android. Can anyone help me please

Comment: Well what have you tried? Do you know how to make a thread in Java?

Comment: I tried to use shared preferences. Is there any other technique